# how to adjust the footer on different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive

https://yosofya.github.io/portfolio-V2.2/index.html

in the attached link of my website. I need the footer to be on the bottom of the Mobile/iPhone screens in Contact and About pages. It looks fine on my PC screen but on not on my iPhone.

I tried @media (max-width)  and then increased the top margin of main-footer to push it down, but it didn't work. I will include the codes for the Contact page.

HTML :

```
<div class="contact-title">

  <h1> class="animated fadeInUp">Contact Me</h1>
  <p> Make sure you provide me with all of the information in case you
    want my help with your project. </p> <br>
    <p>I will be glad to reply as soon as possible. </p>
  </div>

  <form class="contact-form" action="mailto:designist.joey@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

    <input class="form-inputs" type="text" name="Name" size="50" placeholder="Your Name"> <br>
    <input class="form-inputs" type="email" name="Email" size="50" placeholder="Your Email"> <br>
    <textarea class="form-textarea" name="Meesage" rows="8" cols="52" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea> <br>
    <button class="form-button" type="submit" value="Send">Submit</button>


  </form>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .contact-title h1 {

 font-size: 7rem;
 margin-bottom: 20px;

}

 .contact-title p {
  margin: 2px 0;


}

.contact-form {

margin-top: 100px;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {

.main-footer { margin-top:600px;}

 }

 .main-footer p {

 padding-bottom: 100px;
 letter-spacing: 7px;
 margin: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following to your style.css:

```
@media (orientation:portrait) and (min-height: 1080px){
    body, html{
      margin:0;
      height:100%;
    }
}

@media (orientation:portrait) and (min-height: 1080px){
    .container-fluid {
      height: 100%;
    }
}

@media (orientation:portrait) and (min-height: 1080px){
    .main-footer.sticky-bottom {
      position: absolute; 
      left: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0;
    }
}

@media (orientation:portrait) and (min-height: 1080px){
    .contact-background {
      height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Then, add the class 'sticky-bottom' to about.html and contact.html:

```
<div class="main-footer sticky-bottom">
```

This should be commented or removed:

```
/* @media (max-width:600px) {

.main-footer { margin-top:600px;}

} */
```

Comment: This worked just fine. Thank you so much for your effort and time.

So I should use this code on all my projects? I just wonder why this didn't work tho @media screen 
(max-width:600px) {
.contact-form { background-color: blue;}
}

Comment: Yes. You may use this on your project. Did you ask why don't we use @media screen (max-width:600px)? This will not work because it does not fulfil some condition. For eg, when our browser in desktop resizes to smaller than 600px. I just updated to remove the media (max-width:600px) {

.main-footer { margin-top:600px;}

}

Comment: Got it. Really happy with helpful community and helpful people like you. thanks for helping a new developer out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-footer {
     margin-top: 0px;
 }
}
```

Comment: i just did and nothing has happened. the footer is still in the middle of an iPhone screen

Comment: it might be you have some other overriding of css. I tired in the developer tool.